# Can't Log into Strapi after Accidentally Setting User to 'Active False'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, github, strapi

On the Strapi application, I accidentally checked the 'active false' box for the user when it should have been 'true.' Since then, I can't log in to Strapi. I'm convinced that to fix this issue, I need to go into the database, but I can't find which file I should modify to change my user's status back to 'active true.'

Database: SQLite

Language: JavaScript

I tried to back up an old version on GitHub, but no success...

I also tried to filter all active elements in VS Code, but I can't figure out which one I should fix.

Comment: if it's a sqlite database, can't you just log into the database and make this change manually?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I opened SQLite, I saw where is the problem. I changed :
 is active "0" to is active"1". 
I exported the db in Json. 
But the database doesn't update. I don't know how to do it... 
I'm still learning how backend works ...

Comment: Why not just save and overwrite the sqlite database file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set your account as Active = false, if you have no other Admin account that is Active = true.
So one thing would be to connect with your active Admin account - and re-activate your account.

Then if you want, you can connect to the SQLite database that is in the ./tmp folder of your application and update the `admin_users` table, and the column `is_active` => 1

This should reactivate your Admin User